Error en verificación de token JWT NestJS
tengo una API y quiero implementar Guards para controlar ciertos accesos a varios endpoints.
Tengo este guard:
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) { }

async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const { authorization }: any = request.headers;

        if (!authorization || authorization.trim() === '') {
            throw new UnauthorizedException('Please provide token');
        }
        const authToken = authorization.replace(/bearer/gim, '').trim();

        const resp = await this.authService.validateToken(authToken);

        request.decodedData = resp;

        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('auth error - ', error.message);
        throw new ForbiddenException(error.message || 'session expired! Please sign In');
    }
}

}
que llama a la verificación del auth.service.ts
    validateToken(token: string) {
    return this.jwtService.verify(token, { secret: process.env.JWT_TOKEN_SECRET});
}

el cúal siempre me devuelve el error "auth error - invalid signature". He creado una funcion basica para comprobar el token que paso a la llamada y el JWT.TOKEN.SECRET y siempre me devuelve que es el mismo... no se porque la funcion verify me devuelve ese error. Espero vuestra ayuda.
Un saludo.
